# Generics using comparisons

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class in C# where I would like to implement methods to do operations in generics array. For example, I would like to get the maximum component value from a generic array. In my case, it would be enough to consider just numeric types (int, long, double...)

```
public class NumericCalculation<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public static T getMax (T[] array)
    {
        T maxValue = default(T);
        if ( array.Length > 0) {
            maxValue = array[0];                 
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
                if (array[i] > maxValue)
                {
                    maxValue = array[i];
                }
            }            
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

But this returns the error :
"Error  2   Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'"

Is there an interface that I am skipping or something? Is possible to do this generic method to generic arrays of numbers?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a known shortcoming of C#; it is a frequently requested feature to have the ability to constrain generics to types that provide certain operators.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you just want:

```
return array.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

But to answer your specific question, you can use [`CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx), which is a member of the `IComparable<T>` interface that you have constrained the array element-type to:

```
if(array[i].CompareTo(maxValue) > 0) { ... }
```

But personally, I would use [`Comparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f.aspx) instead as it handles `null` references better. This isn't all that important in your case as you are only interested in primitive numeric value-types (all structs):

```
if(Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(array[i], maxValue) > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going to use Comparer<T>.Default.

Answer (score 2):

use next code to compare object of generic types. `CompareTo` is defined in `IComparable<T>` interface

```
if (array[i].CompareTo(maxValue) > 0)
{
    maxValue = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `CompareTo()` in place of the comparaison operators.
Also, Max is already implemented with Linq:

```
return new[] {1,2,9,4,45}.Max();
```